# Add lines of different lengths to plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

In this trivial example I extract a portion of x to make y & y1. To plot y1 in the correct position I used NaN padding in the front. I'm wondering whether NaN padding is considered the best practice or is there some way to directly specify the X coordinate where I want the y1 line segment plotted?

```
figure(500);
hold off;
x = rand(1,100);
plot(x);

y = x(20:60)+3;
hold on;
plot(y);

y1 = horzcat(repmat(nan,1,19), (y+3));

plot(y1);
```

Comment: in case you were unaware: rather than using `repmat` in your example, you can use `nan(1,19)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main goal is just to display the sub-set of data within the proper range, seems like you could just specify the x-range directly, like:

```
x_range = 20:60;
y = x(x_range)+3;
hold on;
plot(y);

plot(x_range, y+3);
grid on
```

Which gives the identical result you got using Nans:

[image]